# Is turning graphite carbon into diamond industrially doable?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, carbon-allotropes

I've read somewhere on the Internet that heating graphite at 4200°K at a sufficiently high pressure would turn it into diamond.

This chart seems to support this idea: [image]

Is that doable industrially?

Comment: The ° symbol is used for temperature scales other than kelvin.  For example, 4200K, but 70°C or 98.6°F.

Answer (score 9):

[It has been done since 1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_diamond) and has been a commercial success for some time. Many products now have [diamond-like coatings](http://www.ibccoatings.com/dlc-coating-diamond-like-carbon-coating-ceratough-d), produced comparatively inexpensively through vapor deposition without need for high pressure.

BTW, in English "burning" means to set on fire, oxidize; I believe you mean "heating graphite", and, as your graph shows, **pressure** is needed as well as heat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are these synthetic diamonds as valuable as the natural ones ? I mean, do they have any use in jewelry ?

Comment: There are many adds for man-made diamond jewelry, for example http://www.diamondnexus.com/pure-carbon-man-made-diamonds.html. As in synthetic sapphire, made since 1902, it is cheaper to make the artificial product (and the artificial material is also of more use in manufacture). Curiously, I believe natural *quartz* crystal (used in resonators etc.) are more used than the artificially grown crystals.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Apparently natural quartz is [no longer](http://highfreqelec.summittechmedia.com/Dec07/HFE1207_Tutorial.pdf) common as natural quartz has many defects and impurities. Much like as you mention for sapphire, artificial quartz is more useful for manufacturing as it can be made in defect-less shapes that are simpler to cut appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @Michael D. M. Dryden! Though I had read that Bell Labs had issues with growth of a polymorph of SiO2 taking over from the desired quartz  after hydrothermal apparatus had been cycled a few times, I should have realized that problem would be overcome.

Answer (score 4):

You want to **heat** graphite at high pressure, not burn it - but yes, high-T, high-p will work.

> Is that doable industrially?

There is a rather lengthy and informative Wikipedia article for [synthetic diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_diamond) that illustrates (in part) the use of this process - HPHT, for "high pressure, high temperature"(using a high-purity source of carbon, not necessarily graphite) in industry. Note that there are several industrial processes mentioned in addition to HPHT.